# REGEX Format to not allow two numerical values side by side

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex format that would allow alphanumerical values but does not allow two or more integers to be next to each other.

For example:

A1AAAA - is match

123 - not match

111 - not match

159 - not match

A172 - not match

92A - not match

A1A1A1 - is match

Most of what I searched shows either consecutive (123) or identical (111) examples. 
I tried

```
^([a-z0-9A-Z])
```

but this does not produce the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a negative lookahead here:

```
^(?!.*\d\d)[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

```js
var pass = "abc1def7";
var fail = "abc123";
console.log(/^(?!.*\d\d)[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(pass));
console.log(/^(?!.*\d\d)[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(fail));
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked! I didn't know you could use \d for the digits :) I was doing something like (?!.*[0-9][0-9]). Learned something new today. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, can `[A-Za-z0-9]*` be simply `.*` ? - Why we need `.*` in `.*\d\d` ?

Comment: @Philippe If you read the OP closely, you will see that he is expecting only letters and numbers.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, OP says "allow alphanumerical values", but there no `only`, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `/\d{2}/` matches - if it does, then you have two digits side-by-side:

```js
for (const str of ['A1AAAA', '123', '111', '159', 'A172', 'A1A1A1']) {
  console.log(!/\d{2}/.test(str));
}
```